# Change a value from a specific row to in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently tying to change some specific values from some specific rows in a data frame with dimensions (401, 2).

The data frame looks like this:

`logFC        pval
cg00035864  2.931898e-02 0.519802679
cg00061679 -9.465129e-05 0.519802679
cg00063477 -1.360574e-01 0.244373340
cg00121626  7.946710e-03 0.611252125
cg00212031 -6.052011e-02 0.774827599
cg00213748 -9.248549e-02 0.851445095
cg00214611  8.384351e-02 0.519802679
cg00223952  2.184674e-03 0.998934883
cg00243321  9.606841e-02 0.519802679
cg00271873  1.781436e-01 0.605388199
cg00272582  1.186292e-01 0.191905652
cg00308367  1.496136e-02 0.791579139
cg00311963  1.260400e-01 0.519802679
cg00335297  1.819981e-01 0.405942400
cg00455876  1.107911e-01 0.519802679
cg00576139 -9.465129e-05 0.519802679
cg00599377  9.778042e-02 0.519802679
cg00639218  1.005280e-01 0.719199850
cg00676506  2.603663e-02 0.706729687
cg00679624 -3.499232e-02 0.735048055
cg00762184  3.561985e-02 0.039468075
cg00789540  1.296961e-01 0.519802679
cg00876332 -1.240570e-01 0.991495608
cg00975375  1.242095e-01 0.519802679
cg01053349  6.237889e-02 0.938655973
cg01061520  3.988364e-02 0.529964491
cg01073572 -9.700589e-02 0.000829731
cg01086462 -5.650370e-02 0.519802679
cg01141334  1.130912e-01 0.883360324
cg01209756  9.301333e-02 0.519802679`

What I would like is to change the values from those rows from the column logFC that don't pass a 5% FDR (column pval, which is already adjusted).

I was doing this in a very rough way, just checking which one where not significant and then change them into 0. As the following way:

`data[data$pval >= 0.05,]`

- Here I look which rows are the ones that I want to change. Let's put an example that are the rows 2,3,5,8,10 and 11 from the original data frame. Then I proceed like this:

`data$logFC[c(2,3,5,8,10,11)] <- 0`

The current problem is that I used to do this in data frame that had a dimension 15, 2. Right now, as said before, the dimension is way larger (401, 2). So I can't do it "manually".

Does somebody know an effective way to do this?

Thank you very much,

Aina

Comment: The proposed solution does not work if the new value is calculated from another one, for example `df$logFC[df$pval >= 0.05] <- df$pval + 3`

Answer (score 9):

A piece of code like this should work:

```
df$logFC[df$pval >= 0.05] <- 0
```

Where df is your dataframe.

Comment: I see I was 46s too slow...

Comment: btw, isn't this question a duplicate of for instance this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871614/replacing-values-from-a-column-using-a-condition-in-r

(I have too low rep to comment, except on my own)

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to do this would be

```
df$logFC[df$pval >= 0.05] <- 0
```

This is certainly fast enough for your `420 x 2` data frame.

This is *very* basic R programming. If you are planning on using R more often, I recommend doing a tutorial or something like [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com)

On a side-note, don't use `data` as a name for you data frame, because the name `data` is actually reserved for other purposes. I recommend using `df` or so