# Fill in empty values in column of dataframe by condition

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have the followin dataframe. Now I want to fill in the empty values in "product" by determining the value of the code 44 and 90. 44 should be "shirt" and 90 "sweater".

What's the best way to do this? With a for loop?

```
data = data.frame("code" = c(44,78,21,90,100,44,90), "product" = c("","hat","shoe","","umbrella","",""))
> data
  code  product
1   44         
2   78      hat
3   21     shoe
4   90         
5  100 umbrella
6   44         
7   90
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13871614/4137985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` first convert the product variable to character (from factor), then use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  mutate(product = case_when(product == "" & code == 44 ~ "shirt",
                             product == "" & code == 90 ~ "sweater",
                             TRUE ~ product))

  code  product
1   44    shirt
2   78      hat
3   21     shoe
4   90  sweater
5  100 umbrella
6   44    shirt
7   90  sweater
```

Using `base`, same idea - first convert factors to character than then use  `ifelse`

```
i <- sapply(data, is.factor)
data[i] <- lapply(data[i], as.character)

data$product[data$product == ""] <- ifelse(data$code[data$product == ""] == 44, "shirt", "sweater")
data
  code  product
1   44    shirt
2   78      hat
3   21     shoe
4   90  sweater
5  100 umbrella
6   44    shirt
7   90  sweater
```

Also worth noting, if you use `data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` all the factor converting becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` and use the indices for subsetting.

```
i <- match(data$code, c(44, 90))
j <- !is.na(i)
data$product[j] <- c("shirt", "sweater")[i[j]]
data
#  code  product
#1   44    shirt
#2   78      hat
#3   21     shoe
#4   90  sweater
#5  100 umbrella
#6   44    shirt
#7   90  sweater
```