# How do I convert a numeric table of that contains percentages in a Data Frame in R to a numeric table with ones and zeros given a threshold

Tags: r, numeric, binary-data

Sorry everyone if this is already in another post, but I am totally new here and super green with R.

So what I am trying to achieve is that all values from a table with percentages above or equal to 15% should become a 1
and all values below 15% should become 0

I was thinking of gsub but can the "to be replaced" be a condition?

Comment: Please add a small reproducible example. If you actually have percent signs, probably use `sub` to get rid of them so you can do a numeric conversion, then you can test them based on value. But we can't help you with code without seeing a data structure, preferably in a copy/pasteable format, e.g., `dput(your_table[1:3, ])` for the first 3 rows.

Comment: If you need help making a reproducible example, [this FAQ has lots of r-specific tips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for trying to help i managed to solve my issues with this:
[Replacing values from a column using a condition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871614/replacing-values-from-a-column-using-a-condition-in-r)

Surely yours would have helped too but I just could not use it because of my limitations. Thanks all for helping though!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   across(everything(), ~ case_when(.x >= 15 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(perc = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.13, 0.8))
df %>%
  mutate(perc = ifelse(perc < 0.15, 0, 1))
```

Comment: df= name of the new object I am creating (I am adding it as a table to my data frame)                   data.frame = is the name of my data frame                                                                                            perc = is the name of my pre-existing table in the df with the percentages                                      i get the following error: "Error: unexpected '=' in:  "  the last line of code

Comment: No I think you are misunderstanding. I created my own data frame using df <- data.frame(c(0.1, 0.4, 0.13, 0.8)) to show how it works.

If you already have a data frame you can skip this step and use your own data frame. 

Something like:

library(dplyr)
[your data frame] %>% 
    mutate([your percentage column] = ifelse([your percentage column] < 0.15, 0, 1))

Comment: still Error: unexpected '=' in: mutate([your percentage column] = ifelse([your percentage column] < 0.15, 0, 1))

Comment: UPDATE: found a solution that worked for me here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871614/replacing-values-from-a-column-using-a-condition-in-r - Surely yours would have helped but I just could not use it because of my limitations. Thanks for helping though!